# Random background image through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to update the background image of a phonegap application every time the user loads the page. The choice of the background image is randomized... The images simply are not loading, however. I am wondering if it is an issue with Angular and jQuery? I am currently implementing Cordova, AngularJS (and Ionic), and jQuery in the application.

Here is a snippet of my code:

In the header of my index.html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var images = ['background.png', 'background2.png', 'background3.png', 'background4.png', 'background5.png', 'background6.png'];
        $(".front-page").css({'background-image': 'url(img/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)] + ')'});
    });
```

The .front-page class in my separate style.css:

```
.front-page {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Which is then applied to the front page of the application:

```
<script id="main.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" class="front-page">
    <ion-content scroll="false">
        ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</script>
```

The paths and image names are all correct, but the background is showing up blank. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you do a console.log to check if the paths are correctly generated.

Comment: add your HTML as well

Comment: I just did one and the paths are correctly generated, each time the picked background image is random, but still nothing is showing up in the emulator...

Comment: @emilywhou Check your network panel, make sure the images loaded correctly and didn't 404 error. The path of inline CSS is relative to the HTML document.

Comment: So I console.log my url paths, which are correct, but when I console.log the css property of background-image using jQuery, nothing shows up. It seems jQuery failed to set the css property... Any suggestions?

Comment: is not background-image in jquery its backgroundImage (well, in javascript)

Comment: @SebastianUrielMurawczik jQuery will resolve `background-image` to `backgroundImage`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara in all jquery versions? i had trouble with that in the past...

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle of your problem so we can see what problem is there....

Comment: @emilywhou is this jquery inside your template, try doing this in the onload or adding this snippet to your template.

Answer (score 0):

Could be caused by a variety of reasons:

1. What device/ OS are you testing with? Older Webkit/webview may not support `background-size: cover;`
2. Have you specified the size of the container class `.front-page` as in `height: 100%; width: 100%`
3. What are the file size and resolution of these .png files? Higher res images will degrade performance.

These aside, we have past experiences with PhoneGap on Android 4.0.2 to 4.3 where `background-images` would randomly fail to render. 1 page load out of 10 would fail to display the background image. And there is no visible explanation, no console error, no CSS error. Same lines would run on all other platforms with no trouble.